# Can't add local users to local group on Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a Windows 2003 server that is joined to a domain. I have two local accounts on the server that need to be added to a local group on the server. When I try to add either account, I get this prompt: “The following error occurred while attempting to save properties for group AGROUP on computer ABC123: More data is available.” But when I look in event viewer, there are not any new logs around the time to give me any more clues as to what is preventing this. While trying to use the CMD prompt to accomplish the task, it says that it fails with system error 234. In looking up there error, all I found was that it means “more data is available.”

Other info:

- one of the local accounts is an admin account but the other is not
- the local group is not an administrators group
- no other member servers in this domain have this issue

Steps I have tried:

- rebooted the server
- disabled the anti-virus suite
- created a new (different) local user and new (different) local group
- renamed the user and group
- deleted the original group and recreated it (I also tried creating it with a different name)
- I also saw an old local account we no longer use on the box, and when I tried to delete that account, I was given the same error message
- I tried deleting the local accounts and I was given the same error message
- I tried using group policy to add them

Do you folks have any tips or insight for me?

Comment: By any chance is one of the local group members a user that has the same name as the name of the domain the server is joined to?

Comment: @user5870571, no the account is not named the same as the domain. There is also a domain account with the same name, but I make sure to select the local account when trying to add it to the group.

Comment: For grins change the local username to something that is not a domain username and try again.

Comment: @user5870571, I believe I have already tried that, but I will try again tomorrow to make sure.